# VFP spt querying SqlServer 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, visual-foxpro

I have to support a SqlServer2008 R2 backend.  In the following SQL statement

```
lcSql = "SELECT field1, field2, 00000.00 as CalcField FROM myTable"
SqlExec(lnHandle,lcSql,"csrMyTable")
```

in previous versions (include 2008) the CalcField would be returned as N(8,2), but with R2 it is returned as N(4,2).

I use this field to do further calculations and then stuff the calc value into the CalcField.  This is now a problem when the CalcField is too small to hold the value.

i have considered issuing

```
lcSql = "SELECT field1, field2, 99999.99 as CalcField FROM myTable"
SqlExec(lnHandle,lcSql,"csrMyTable")

SELECT csrMyTable
REPLACE ALL CalcField WITH 0
```

I wonder if any one has a different solution.  I use this throughout my system for reports, displays, etc. so it would require a fairly major change.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try with CAST(0.00 AS N(8,2)) as CalcField

```
lcSql = "SELECT field1, field2, CAST(0.00 AS N(8,2)) as CalcField FROM myTable"
SqlExec(lnHandle,lcSql,"csrMyTable")
```